# How to target oldest iphone version possible with latest iOS SDK and detect missing symbols from newer APIs?

Tags: xcode, ios

I am compiling a project that is using a function only defined in iOS SDK 4.1. However, I am able to set the ios deployment target to 3.2 and compile it without any warning.

IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 3.2

How comes xcode doesn't warn me. Am I missing something. I have a larger project and I what to determine what could be me minimum target, how do should I proceed?

However, documentation clearly states:

"Note: If the SDK you’re using to build the application is more recent than the application’s target iOS release (for example, the active SDK is iOS 4.2 and iOS Deployment Target is iPhone OS 4.0), Xcode displays build warnings when it detects that your application is using a feature that’s not available in the target OS release."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Building_and_Running_Applications/building_and_running_applications.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH6

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, that documentation is wrong. I've never been able to see warnings when I've used too-new features.

Comment: Never seen warnings, does a param is needed for the compiler ?

Comment: This is terrible! Has nobody found a solution for this!? Now, we need to test all the apps to get runtime errors for everything instead of compiler errors/warnings... hm...

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we keep old Xcode install and run trough command line :

/Developer3.2.6/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project project.xcodeproj -target UnitTests -sdk iphonesimlator4.3

If the  compilation fails, the log are clear about usage of undeclared code (from iOS 5 for instance). Of course, Jenkins continuous integration is our friend for doing that.